# What is the relation between missile fin deflection limit and altitude?

Tags: control-surfaces

What's the relation between limit of deflection for aerodynamic control surfaces (tail control) and altitude for surface to air missiles?

Also how can the fin deflection range (Max/Min) be determined for any altitude?

Please mention any reference text related to the subject.

Comment: From Missile Guidance and Control Systems by George M. Siouris, I know that  Maximum fin deflection is limited by the missile velocity and
the altitude band in which the missile is flying but i cant find any procedure to determine this upper limit.